# OpenPyXL - How to set print area for a worksheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to use OpenPyXL to create invoices. I have a worksheet with an area to be printed and some notes outside of that range. I have most everything working but I am unable to find anything in the API for one function. Is there a way to set the print area on a worksheet?

I am able to find lots of print settings, but not the print area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In the current version of openpyxl (2.5.4 at time of writing), this is done using:

```
Worksheet.print_area = "A1:L25"
```

Docs are [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/print_settings.html?highlight=print_area#add-a-print-area).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently directly possible. You could do it manually by creating a definedNamed using the reserved `xlnm` prefix (see `Worksheet.add_print_title` for an example.

Comment: FWIW this feature is now possible in 2.4 (you'll need a checkout): `ws.print_rows = "1:1"; `ws.print_cols = "A:A"`

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
wb.create_named_range('_xlnm.Print_Area', ws, 'A1:U56',scope=0)
```

worked for me, the scope is mandatory.